# why are asp.net hidden fields becoming visible

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

this the javascript code I am using to access the values but every time this runs all hidden fields become visible why?

```
function PopulateTableComboBox(ID) {

var myValues = new Array();
var startsWith = "TABLE=";

for (var index = 0; index < document.getElementsByTagName("input").length; index++) {

    if (document.getElementsByTagName("input")[index].type = 'hidden' && document.getElementsByTagName("input")[index].id.substring(0, startsWith.length) === startsWith) {
        myValues.push(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[index].value);
    }
}
       }
```

even the viewsate's hidden fields are effected to the point where the asp.net buttons turn into square box with text in it. I have attached a before and after picture[image: this is the before the javascript function is run][image: This is after the javascript function is run]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `=` instead of `==`

Your code

```
 document.getElementsByTagName("input")[index].type = 'hidden'
```

Change it to

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[index].type == 'hidden'
```

Comment: As of right now I HATE javascript Totally and completely hate it. Why because its a pain to debug I mean I use chrome developer tools (highly  recommended) but its only useful to use with break points after that your on your own coming from a C# background in vs2010 I  would have little squiggly lines next to the equal sign pointing out the error but whit chrome dev tools no assistance whatsoever... Thank you.... Man I feel stupid :(